# Three.js Completely transparent material with specular map fully visible

Tags: three.js, specular

I need to render a food tray with meat inside to showcase some packaging designs for a client. I am stuck at the material for the plastic film which encloses the tray's contents. I was planning to use a specular map or a normal map to obtain the glossy effect, but the only think I can get is fully transparent or fully shaded with specular map. Neither suits my purpose.

This is my current material setup:

```
"DbgIndex" : 1,
"DbgName"  : "plasticFilm",
"shading" : "Phong",
"colorDiffuse"  : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
"colorAmbient"  : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
"colorSpecular"  : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
"transparent" : true,
"transparency"  : 0.01,
"specularCoef"  : 100.0,
"mapSpecular"    : "film-bump.jpg",
"mapBumpScale" : 0.2,
"vertexColors" : false
```

Live code [here](http://demo.adrianmoisa.ro/flexikom/). 
JSON tray file [here](http://demo.adrianmoisa.ro/flexikom/models/packaging/tray1/tray1.js).

In inspector the materials can be accessed with the following commands:
`showcase.scene.children` OR `showcase.materials`

Thank you!

Comment: you might want to reduce your ambient term to (0.2,0.2,0.2)

Comment: I have tryed as you suggested, but it only reduces the amount of light the material receives / reflects, I still I have to push transparency to high values in order to seethe specular map effect.

Comment: try `opacity` instead of `transparency`

Comment: As far as I learned untill now `transparency:` is the term used in JSON model 3 to define `opacity:` property on material. They mean the same thing.